# run maven project form github in eclipse

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, configuration

I have imported a Git project from [this url](https://github.com/sagioto/LipReading.git) to my Eclipse.
How can I run this project? I am not familiar to maven and javaEE. please guide me to run this project. I am confused. 
I have installed eclipse javaEE Kepler. but i do not know how to configure this project to run? what is type of my run? maven build or junit?

Comment: Select the `main()` class of the app you want to run, then run that as a Java Application

Comment: should i use a eclipse ee or eclipse standard?

Comment: It doesn't matter.  However, you should also install the Maven connector.

Comment: in my project, i have import javax.servlet.http.httpservletrequest. so i think it should be javaEE project, so i downloaded Java EE IDE. and it has maven integration in it. should i install any thing more?